# Design Support TabLayout

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

I'm playing around with the Design Support Library TabLayout. My problem is that the title of one of the tabs is too long and so, it is drawn on 2 lines instead of 1. I'm wondering if there's a way scale the title text size to ensure that all titles are drawn on 1 line.

Here's a screenshot to better explain my problem:[image]

In case the details are important, I'm using Design Support TabLayout, a ViewPager and a FragmentPagerAdapter to populate my tabs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you will see in TabLayout there is a constant                                    private static final int MAX_TAB_TEXT_LINES = 2;                              and in TabView(LinearLayout) there is text view that is having a max lines set to textView.setMaxLines(MAX_TAB_TEXT_LINES); <br> So you can provide your custom view to the tab having set to max line one aand it will ellipsize at the end. i.e. tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(View v)

Comment: @Adam Do you get solution??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change font size or another params of tabLayout in `styles.xml`.  For example:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextAppearance.Design.Tab</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextAppearance.Design.Tab" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmitriy, this sheds some light on my problem. Changing the text size will fix my immediate problem but I wonder if this fixes the problem for all devices. I want to ensure that tabs on devices of all sizes and resolutions take up only one line. Do you know if there a way to force the tab layout to fit the content of the tab onto one line?

Comment: I don't know about singleLine like paramertre of textView, but you can add support for different devices. For textSize you can write value from dimen.xml files of different layouts. Watch this http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Answer (score 21):

have you set:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    ..
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Comment: setting it to scrollable does set it onto one line but now the tabs aren't equally spaced. Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: Hi Adam,  the actual solution to your question is above from Dmitriy Chernov - however changing the text size doesn't follow Material Guidelines - https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage  look specifically under subtitle content.  It states to either wrap on two lines, or have as a scrollable tabs (as per suggestion) - the answer I gave follows guidelines and keeps your tab text on one line.  you can try : app:tabMinWidth="dp value" in the TabLayout XML and play around with a dp value that fits your largest tab text

Comment: exactly what I'm was looking for, thanx!

Comment: @MarkKeen I dont know why it doesnt help me. I have tabMode set to scrollable and it still doesnt put the text onto single line. :/

Answer (score 0):

They claimed to have fix this issue, but it's not working as of support library 22.2.1.

See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175516

Comment: I agree, I am on 23.1.1 and still wraps; so I went with enabling scrollable

Answer (score 0):

Update design support library to `23.1.0`. They have fixed this issue, but your text size changes too

Comment: Text size via code doesn't work in 23.1.0, but you can set it via styles.xml as Dmitriy Chernov has done